# Anomaly detection using Clustering techniques on data with skewed features

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-transformation, k-means, skewness

I am working on finding anomalies in data. My dataset consists of 2 variables - Price of item and Volume of item purchased in a single checkout. I do not have information on the item other than its price. I am trying to find anomalies (e.g. high value items bought in large numbers in a single checkout) in the dataset using unsupervised learning technique.

[image]

Above is a univariate plot of **Volume**

[image]

Above is a univariate plot of **Purchase_amount**

In both plots it appears that the data is very right-skewed, and hence K-means may not work very well with the data. Here is a scatter plot of Volume vs Purchase_amount:

[image]

I tried using boxcox transformation on both the variables using

```
library(EnvStats)
boxcox(volume, optimize = TRUE)
boxcox(purchase_amount, optimize = TRUE)
```

Then I did a log transformation on Purchase_amount and a square root transformation on Volume.

```
sqrtvol <- sqrt(volume) 
qqnorm(logpa)
qqline(logpa)
qqnorm(sqrtvol)
qqline(sqrtvol)
```

However, the qqplots seem to show that after transformation the data still does not look very normal. For instance, this is the qqplot for the transformed Volume. I am not too sure why the plots look strange.

[image]

Not sure how I should approach this question. Should I explore DBSCAN instead? Is there a good way to choose a minPts value for a dataset with roughly around 400+ data points?

Appreciate any help / suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: By "anomaly detection using clustering techniques" you are assuming there are **more than one** clusters/distributions that generated the data. How do you reach such an assumption?

Comment: Thank you for your question, Haotian. The sample dataset is obtained by stratified random sampling from the population. So I picked x number of data points from each strata. For instance I have stratas such as 'High purchase amount, High volume', 'Mid purchase amount, High volume', ..., 'Low purchase amt, Low vol'. (roughly 9 strata). I defined what is meant by high, medium and low for the prices and volume. Not sure if they can be thought of as clusters here?

Comment: Yes they are clusters, manually defined clusters. It's a good practive to use expert knowledge to define clusters when there's not enough samples. If there is abundant amount of samples, expert knowledge is not that useful anymore. It all depends on real situations. Also, if you can access the un-stratified samples, probably trying some simple anomaly detection method first before complexing the model. For example use a gamma distribution to model the distribution of volume, and make the samples with cdf value greater than 0.999 as outliers. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Haotian. So if I understand correctly, for instance if I were to use a gamma distribution to model the distribution of volume, and example some other distribution to model distribution of purchase_amount, then I have to flag the outliers for these 2 variables independently? Because the data is not univariate. Each row of data has 2 features (Purchase_amount & Volume). Not too sure how this works..

Comment: Yes you understand correctly, you can either use two gamma distributions to model the two features and flag outliers independently, or use one Wishart distribution (kind of like a multivariate gamma distribution) to model the two features together to find out outliers. If you are unfamilar with Wishart distribution, you can log your data (to convert your sample range from $(0,+\infty)$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$) and model the logged data with a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks Haotian for your help :)